# How to tell when New-AzSqlDatabaseImport has finished?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to import a .bacpack into a new Azure database as part of a DevOps pipeline. I've a PowerShell script that does actually do the import, however I need to do some operations on the database after the import has completed. These are failing because they are running before the import has finished.

I'm trying to detect the completion of the import like this:

```
$status = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport @newDbParameters

# Wait for database to deploy
$waitCount = 0
$waitDelay = 5
while (($status | Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus).Status -eq 'InProgress') {
    $waitCount++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Waiting for database creation." -Status "Count: $waitCount"
    Start-Sleep $waitDelay
}
Write-Progress -Activity "Database to created." -Completed

# Output results
$result = $status | Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
$result
if ($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {
    Write-Progress "Database deployed." -Completed
    Write-Host "Database Deployed"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Database did not deploy '$($result.Status)'-'$($result.ErrorMessage)'"
    Throw $result.ErrorMessage
}
```

This isn't working however because the status can be strings like `Running, Progress = 5.00 %`

Update:

Just to add a couple more details, I'm running this on Azure DevOps on a release server provided my Microsoft. I'm running it in an Azure PowerShell task V5.*. I added a couple of lines in my script to output $PSVersionTable and Get-Module Az.Sql. I've included the logged output below. As you can see: PowerShell is V7.0.3, Az module is 4.7.0 and Az.Sql is V 2.10.0. The `Running, Progress = 5.00 %` is definitely coming out of the `Status` property and not the `StatusMessage` property.

```
2020-11-07T16:01:19.1265632Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-07T16:01:21.1720968Z Generating script.
2020-11-07T16:01:21.2849730Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-11-07T16:01:21.3454648Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\[REDACTED].ps1'"
2020-11-07T16:01:28.2383178Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2020-11-07T16:01:29.0267158Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_4.7.0\Az.Accounts\1.9.5\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2020-11-07T16:01:31.4671842Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2020-11-07T16:01:32.7361261Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2020-11-07T16:01:33.9818461Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2020-11-07T16:01:35.6660673Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId [REDACTED] -TenantId ***
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4234219Z PSVersionTable
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4322960Z 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4343833Z Name                           Value
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4345708Z ----                           -----
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4346476Z PSVersion                      7.0.3
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4349569Z PSEdition                      Core
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4350222Z GitCommitId                    7.0.3
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4355758Z OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4356853Z Platform                       Win32NT
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4378974Z PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4379723Z PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4380231Z SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4380545Z WSManStackVersion              3.0
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4387506Z Az.Sql
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4675347Z 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4682595Z Name              : Az.Sql
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4684105Z Path              : C:\Modules\az_4.7.0\Az.Sql\2.10.0\Az.Sql.psm1
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4689463Z Description       : Microsoft Azure PowerShell - SQL service cmdlets for Azure Resource Manager in Windows PowerShell 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4690369Z                     and PowerShell Core.
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4690846Z                     
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4691418Z                     For more information on SQL, please visit the following: 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4693344Z                     https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4694862Z Guid              : f088f4ab-1b59-4836-a6e0-4e14d15800c6
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4697620Z Version           : 2.10.0
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4698325Z ModuleBase        : C:\Modules\az_4.7.0\Az.Sql\2.10.0
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4698841Z ModuleType        : Script
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4699266Z PrivateData       : {PSData}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4700897Z AccessMode        : ReadWrite
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4703133Z ExportedAliases   : {[Disable-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtection, Disable-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtection], 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4704800Z                     [Enable-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtection, Enable-AzSqlServerAdvancedThreatProtection], 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4705980Z                     [Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy, Get-AzSqlDatabaseLongTermRetentionPolicy], 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4706882Z                     [Get-AzSqlInstanceTDEProtector, Get-AzSqlInstanceTDEProtector]…}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4710468Z ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-AzSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup, Add-AzSqlDatabaseToFailoverGroup], [Add-AzSqlElasticJobStep, 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4713706Z                     Add-AzSqlElasticJobStep], [Add-AzSqlElasticJobTarget, Add-AzSqlElasticJobTarget], 
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4714478Z                     [Add-AzSqlInstanceKeyVaultKey, Add-AzSqlInstanceKeyVaultKey]…}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4715146Z ExportedFunctions : {}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4715380Z ExportedVariables : {}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4715705Z NestedModules     : {Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Sql}
2020-11-07T16:01:37.4716908Z 
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8406335Z 
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8412106Z OperationStatusLink          : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[REDACTED]/provider
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8414296Z                                s/Microsoft.Sql/locations/uksouth/importExportOperationResults/[REDACTED]
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8415688Z                                [REDACTED]?api-version=2020-02-02-preview
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8416460Z ErrorMessage                 : 
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8417030Z LastModifiedTime             : 11/7/2020 4:01:39 PM
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8417715Z QueuedTime                   : 11/7/2020 4:01:38 PM
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8418302Z RequestType                  : Import
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8418922Z Status                       : Running, Progress = 5.00 %
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8419526Z StatusMessage                : 
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8419842Z PrivateEndpointRequestStatus : {}
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8420140Z 
2020-11-07T16:01:39.8467940Z Database did not deploy 'Running, Progress = 5.00 %'-''
2020-11-07T16:01:40.7865529Z ##[error]ScriptHalted
2020-11-07T16:01:40.9680645Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-11-07T16:01:41.9027974Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy baseline DB from bacpac
```

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: There are some relevant GitHub issues: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13529  https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is an issue introduced in version 2.10.0 of the Az.Sql module. I was able to fix this by setting the `Preferred Azure PowerShell Version` field on the Azure DevOps task to 4.6.0. This version of the Az module contains version 2.9.1 of Az.Sql.

Apparently this has been [fixed in Azure Powershell v5.3.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13529#issuecomment-754941247), though I have not checked personally.

Answer (score 4):

The command `Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus` will return Object `AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatusModel`. The object has some properties. Its property status will return `Succeeded` `InProgress`. Its property StatusMessage will return `progress`(such as `Running, Progress = 5.00 %`). For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqldatabaseimportexportstatus?view=azps-5.0.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell#using-powershell)

For example

```
# Set the resource group name and location for your server
$resourceGroupName = ""
$location = ""
# Set an admin login and password for your server
$adminSqlLogin = ""
$password = ""
# Set server name - the logical server name has to be unique in the system
$serverName = ""
# The sample database name
$databaseName = "myImportedDatabase"
# The storage account name and storage container name
$storageAccountName = ""
$storageContainerName = ""
# BACPAC file name
$bacpacFilename = ""

$importRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $serverName `
    -DatabaseName $databaseName `
    -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "262144000" `
    -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
    -StorageKey $(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0] `
    -StorageUri "https://$storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$storageContainerName/$bacpacFilename" `
    -Edition "Standard" `
    -ServiceObjectiveName "S3" `
    -AdministratorLogin "$adminSqlLogin" `
    -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force)
# Check import status and wait for the import to complete
# Wait for database to deploy

$waitDelay = 5
while (($importRequest | Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus).Status -eq 'InProgress') {
    ($importRequest | Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus).StatusMessage
    Start-Sleep $waitDelay
}


# Output results
$result = $importRequest | Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus
$result
if ($result.Status -eq 'Succeeded') {
    
    Write-Host "Database Deployed"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Database did not deploy '$($result.Status)'-'$($result.ErrorMessage)'"
    Throw $result.ErrorMessage
}
```

Comment: This is fairly identical to the example I gave in the question. My testing of it suggests it doesn't work because the .Status property can give the resutl "Running, Progress = 5.00 %" as well as "InProgress" or "Success".

Comment: @MartinBrown Could you please provide the screenshot of it and the version of your module? According to my test, I just can get "InProgress" or "Success".

Comment: I've added the log to the question. I think it only gives you the the other value for Status if you have a database that takes a while to install. Trouble is because there is no documentation telling what the possible values are its hard to know what to check for.

Comment: @MartinBrown According to my test, if you use `Az.sql` 2.9.1 module, you can get `InProgress` : https://imgur.com/a/vi0nNR9